# "Unable to open project file to perform upgrade" when opening VS2008 project in VS2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, converters

Why do I get an `"Unable to open project file to perform upgrade"` error when opening a `VS2008` project in `VS2010`?

The files are not opened anywhere else.

Comment: How can we know without extra information , such as logs ?

Comment: Do You have maybe some Visual Studio addins? Try to migrate Your solution in safe mode.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: the conversion log is where I got the error message from. Do you want the name of the file?

Comment: @MichaelMocko: didn't work.

Comment: @CJ7 try to move your dev directory and than convert it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common problem.

- Remove the **project.user** file from your solution.
- Restart it.

It should work.

Comment: There was no `project.user` file. There were some `.user` files but deleting them did *not* solve the problem.

Comment: delete the user option (.suo)file and the .sdf file(if there is one) and restart to try again.

Comment: I am sorry. I am out of options. It worked for me sometime back. If you find a way let me know. Maybe its a problem with visual studio?